# Jekyll: parse pages without front matter

Tags: jekyll

As far as I gather, Jekyll parses an included page through the templating stage if and only if it finds a YAML header / front matter. Otherwise it just copies it. Is there a way to force Jekyll to parse an included file *without* a front matter?

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: Why not add the header (create a process which adds the header in a tmp directory, and let those process by Jekyll).

Comment: I wanted to both include a page in another page, and have the page rendered standalone. Actually I refactored around needing to do that, but I'll leave this open because still interested to know if it's possible to do this.

Comment: How about adding empty front matter? Is that an option? It does work.

Comment: Jekyll won't strip it out. It will output "---\n---". If Jekyll would strip YAML headers from includes, that would also work for me. But unfortunately it doesn't because the headers are currently meaningless for includes.

Comment: Jekyll can replace code... so you could replace "---\n---" in your output (wherever that appears).

Comment: @JoostS How do you do this? Can you answer with an example?

Answer (score 0):

**The rule of thumb is that Jekyll will not parse files without front matter.**

However... there is a work-around. You can create an index.html file in the _includes directory without front matter. The Liquid in this file will be interpreted by Jekyll. You can render this include anywhere using:

```
{% include index.html %}
```

This solution is perfect for rendering HTML pages within a Jekyll context (without having the front matter requirement), especially when you want to reuse them. This could be useful for rendering a preview AND showing the code in a code block on another page. The include could be written in a layout file or in an index.md file.

Note that the included filename can be a variable (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/):

```
{% if page.my_variable %}
  {% include {{ page.my_variable }} %}
{% endif %}
```

Also note that if you want to show Liquid examples in this code, you should use:

```
 {% raw %} ... Liquid example ... {% endraw %}
```

If you want a solution work-around for your specific situation, you should share your repository and explain your use case.